# How to run NodeJs api on cpanel

Tags: node.js, cpanel

I have an Angular app running on server but I don`t know how to run Node api as backend.
This is how it looks:
[image]

Inside datesAPI file is my API. How to run it?

Answer (score 0):

If your server has Cloudlinux, you will see the "Setup Node.js App" option for deploying your node application.

- https://i.stack.imgur.com/ICbnr.png
- https://i.stack.imgur.com/F9bVT.png

If your hosting doesn't have Cloudlinux, you can do the followings steps:

- https://docs.cpanel.net/knowledge-base/web-services/how-to-install-a-node.js-application/